# Rendering indexed triangles shows mode GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT in tracer for Opengl ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to render some indexed VBO triangles with following code:

```
    letterFrameSP.useProgram();
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, letterFrame.getBufferVertex());
            glVertexAttribPointer(
                    letterFrameSP.getaPositionLocation(),
                    3,
                    GL_FLOAT,
                    false,
                    letterFrame.getStride(),
                    0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(letterFrameSP.getaPositionLocation());
            glVertexAttribPointer(
                    letterFrameSP.getaNormalLocation(),
                    3,
                    GL_FLOAT,
                    false,
                    letterFrame.getStride(),
                    3*Math3dUtil.BYTES_PER_FLOAT);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(letterFrameSP.getaNormalLocation());
            glVertexAttribPointer(
                    letterFrameSP.getaCubeIndex(),
                    1,
                    GL_FLOAT,
                    false,
                    letterFrame.getStride(),
                    (3+3)*Math3dUtil.BYTES_PER_FLOAT);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(letterFrameSP.getaCubeIndex());
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,letterFrame.getBufferIndex());
glDrawElements(
                        GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                        letterFrame.getTriangleIndexCount(),
                        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                        0);
```

Screen is black, any triangle is rendered. I use the Tracer For Opengl ES and this is the result:

```
glClear(mask = 16640)
glUseProgram(program = 3)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 2)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1101, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 28, ptr = 0x0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 1101)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = -1, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 28, ptr = 0xc)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = -1)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 1, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 28, ptr = 0x18)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 0)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 1)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -20.0, 1.0])
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [3.2629604, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.4142134, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.020202, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.383839, 20.0])
glUniform3f(location = 1229, x = 0,000000, y = 10,000000, z = -10,000000)
glUniform1fv(location = 1230, count = 128, v = [0.0])
glUniform4f(location = 1231, x = 1,000000, y = 0,500000, z = 0,500000, w = 1,000000)
glDrawElements(mode = GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT, count = 3840, type = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices = 0x0)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 0)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 0)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(index = 1101)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(index = -1)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(index = 0)
eglSwapBuffers
```

What means the follow line?

```
glDrawElements(mode = GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT, count = 3840, type = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices = 0x0)
```

I use the mode GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES in glDrawElements function, but in the tracer appears GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT. Why?

Answer (score 4):

The captured trace, which is encoded using protobuf, only contains the numerical values for the arguments.

`GL_TRIANGLES` and `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT` have the same value. From the official OpenGL header file:

```
#define GL_TRIANGLES                      0x0004
...
#define GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT       0x0004
```

The trace display tool just isn't very smart, and picks the wrong enum representation of the numerical value.

These two "enums" having the same value is not a problem in regular OpenGL usage, since they are never used as possible arguments for the same API calls:

- `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT` is a possible value for a bitmask, and can only be passed to specific API calls like `glMapBufferRange()` that expect a corresponding bitmask value.
- `GL_TRIANGLES` is a regular enum, and is passed as argument to `glDraw*()` calls. It happens to have a very low value because it was one of the first values defined in the original version of OpenGL.

So this is harmless. If the trace display tool knew anything about which arguments are valid for which API calls, it could easily display the correct value.